# Dynamics CRM plugin to sync of quote-products and opportunity-products

Tags: c#, plugins, entity, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am a newbie in the MS Dynamics CRM plugin-development and I should develop a plugin that syncronise two entities. 
By default in MS CRM quote-products and opportunity-products are not binded to one another. And boss will realise this feature.

To avoid a conflicts between quote-products and opportunity-products I decided to delete on update of quote-products all opportunity-products from corresponded opportunity. But I am not sure if these opportunity-products have relationsships with other entities.

What can happen if I delete all opportunity-products on update of an quote-product? Can it get problems because of it? I did not find any cause not to do it... Unfortunetely we have no test-system, where I could test it and I have some fear, that I can break something because of my experiments... (we use the online-version of dynamics crm).

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: I may be missing something here but it sounds like your requirements are working against the business logic of MS CRM. If you create a Quote from an Opportunity this marks a milestone in the sales process. If you really need to change the Opportunity changes you'd rather a new Quote but usually you'd create a new Quote revision to document the progress in your sales process. You should discuss with your boss which problem you're actually trying to solve by "synchronizing" Quote-Products and Opportunity-Products. I'd argue that you can't document upsell Quotes comparing them to the initial Opp.

Comment: He ment that it is very usefull and simplier to edit the quote. He told that in the other CRMs he have seen those features.

I am just developer and I have no plan about these processes. Thanks for your hint! I have already assuemed that this is against the business logic. Also, I'm going to speak about it with him.